# How to add response time in gunicorn access log

Tags: python, gunicorn

I have a gunicorn *config.py and need to add response time to gunicorn access log:

Here's what I have:

```
...  
accesslog = some_path/filename
access_log_format = '%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"'
...
```

gunicorn version 19.7.1

Some more details:
*config.py didn't contain the seting access_log_format before, and I thought adding it might help, but even after I added and restarted the process, the access log contains the same parameters as before:

```
<ip> - - [16/Aug/2020:14:11:35 XDT] "POST /ws/v1/sessions?userId=<username> HTTP/1.1" 200 537 "-" "python-requests/2.22.0"
<ip> - - [16/Aug/2020:14:11:56 XDT] "DELETE /ws/v1/sessions HTTP/1.1" 200 139 "-" "python-requests/2.22.0"
<ip> - - [17/Aug/2020:04:05:40 XDT] "GET /ws/v1/data-specs HTTP/1.1" 200 35097 "-" "python-requests/2.22.0"
<ip> - - [17/Aug/2020:09:30:31 XDT] "GET /ws/v1/data-specs HTTP/1.1" 200 35097 "-" "python-requests/2.22.0"
```

I am new to python, gunicorn and web apis. I am unable to figure out how to add response time to the log. What am I doing wrong here? Please help.

Comment: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2404

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation (https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#access-log-format)

The corresponding value for response time miliseconds is `%(D)s`

Comment: Yes, I went through that very briefly too, before posting a query here. But I was not sure what "0.17.0" was and whether that would be applicable to my gunicorn version(19.7.1) Should I add %(D)s to the access_log_format string? Also what is the meaning of version 0.17.0?

Comment: Also it says in that description that %(D)s is the request time. Are response and request times the same?

Comment: D will print response time in microseconds. M will show time in millis.